# Echo file contents to javascript from PHP using fopen(), file_exists() not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, linux, apache

I know there are many different posts concerning this, but none of the posts seemed to help.

I have tried inputting

```
include_path=".:/path/to/dir"
```

along with

```
safe_mode_exec_dir=".:/path/to/dir"
```

into php.ini. I have tried turning safe_mode on, turning allow_url_fopen to On and then putting ftp:// in front of the path, and without the ftp://. I have tried using multiple different ways of opening it including...

```
$folder = $_GET['dir'];

$path = $folder;

$file = fopen($path, 'r');

$lines = array();

while(!feof($file)){
    $lines[] = fgets($file);
}
fclose($file);
```

and

```
$lines = explode("\n", file_get_contents('doc.txt'));
```

I have tried setting permissions to 777 under /var/www/html and permissions on the other directory which is under /home/pi/

Nothing seems to be working.

So. I am completely out of ideas. Please help before my head banging becomes dangerous.

Here is my code for what I am trying to do...

```html
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>';

echo '<response>';

  $folder = $_GET['dir'];
 
  $path = $folder."/myfile.txt";
 
  $file = fopen($path, 'r');
  
  $lines = array();
  
  while(!feof($file)){
   $lines[] = fgets($file);
  }
  fclose($file);
  
  for($x = 0; $x < sizeof($lines); $x++){
   echo $lines[$x];
  }
   
echo '</response>';
?>
```

```html
xmlHttp = createXmlHttpObject();
xmlHttp.open("GET", "getClientData.php?folder="+dir, false);
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && (xmlHttp.status == 200 || xmlHttp.status == 206)) {
     xmlResponse = xmlHttp.responseXML;
     xmlDocumentElement = xmlResponse.documentElement;
     var message = xmlDocumentElement.firstChild.textContent;
}
};
xmlHttp.send();
```

I am running this on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B, Rasbian Jessie, if that has anything to do with it. And Apache2.

It's interesting to note that when I change the php file a little bit to have an if/else statement like "if(file_exists($path)){}else{echo "null"}", if I call alert() in javascript from the input, I DO get "null". That's why my first assumption was a file permission thing or php.ini setting.

Comment: Look at the [`fgets()` examples in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgets.php)

Comment: Once `$lines` gets loaded its an array, look up `foreach` and use it instead of `for`

Answer (score 0):

So I have solved it. And I will give a detailed description as to how I solved it.

First of all, do make sure that allow_url_fopen to be On and to have safe_mode off. Look through both the Apache2 php.ini and the regular php.ini as there is two of them and I believe both have to be set in order for it to work. If you installed php with apache2 on your platform, both php.ini files should be under "/etc/php5". There will be a folder called "apache2" and "cli". Each one has a file.

Secondly, Chrome Web Development Tools are amazing. Press F12 with Chrome open and go to the "Networks" tab. There will be a checkbox that says "Disable Cache" at the top of the tab. This makes sure that Chrome won't cache the results of your changes to your website. KEEP THIS WINDOW OPEN BECAUSE IF YOU CLOSE IT, IT WON'T DISABLE THE CACHE ANYMORE!!! You can also download a Chrome extention like "cache killer" which will disable cached results just the same. Also, with CWDT, the Console Tab is a debugging miracle. I have been programming the site on Aptana, which is not very good at all at noticing small semi colon or bracket errors. Utilize this tool! It will save your life as it did mine!!

Please ask questions or comments if I didn't explain something in detail.